# Import Inquirer as module in Node 13

Tags: node.js, inquirer

I'm having troubles with import of [Inquirer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/inquirer) using modules in `Node 13.12.0`. Any other `import` works well. As long as I've been using `Node 12.x` with `require()` it worked well.

My use-case of `anything.mjs`

```
import fs from "fs"; // works well
import inquirer from 'inquirer'; // undefined
```

So I've tried to import only one exported module

```
import {prompt} from 'inquirer'; // The requested module 'inquirer' does not provide an export named 'prompt'
```

also tried:

```
import * as inquirer from 'inquirer'; // [Module] { default: undefined }
```

I've also tried to `require()` but it is not defined in modules anymore.

---

How should I properly import `Inquirer` in `Node 13.12.0` using `modules`?

Comment: Try this : https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_createrequire_filename

Comment: @AyushGupta it works well. Could you please provide explanation to answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_createrequire_filename), you can use `require` in ESM in Node 13 as follows:

```
import { createRequire } from 'module';
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);

const inquirer = require('inquirer');
```

Answer (score 2):

inquirer just released [v9.0](https://github.com/SBoudrias/Inquirer.js/releases/tag/inquirer%409.0.0) and migrated to ESM modules.
So now this will simply work:

```
import inquirer from 'inquirer';

const response = await inquirer.prompt([
  {
    type: 'input',
    name: 'question',
    message: 'Want to answer?'
  }
]);

console.log(response.question);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ES Modules and enquirer 2.3.6 I am using it this way. We could pass types to prompt object.

```
import enquirer from 'enquirer';

const enquirerObj =  new enquirer();

const response = await enquirerObj.prompt({
    type:'confirm',
    name: 'question',
    message: 'Want to answer?'
  });

 console.log(response);
```